# Next.JS and Nodemailer, Sending an email from contact form

Tags: javascript, node.js, gmail, next.js, nodemailer

I have a problem with my contact form in next.js, I don't have any errors (that are shown), everything worked untill deployment (on Vercel). I fetch my form, and have status 200, but I do not recive my email on Gmail. Also I don't recive any additional information.
I've recived emails, when I tested my app on "dev" and "build".
I've also have "less secure apps" option in Gmail account.

Here's my code in Next.JS:

fetch method in contact.js:

```
 fetch("/api/contact", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          name: mailName,
          email: mailAddress,
          text: mailText,
        }),
      }).then((res) => {
        console.log("Fetch: ", res);
        res.status === 200
        ?
        router.push("/success")
          : router.push("/error");
```

in api/contact.js

```
require("dotenv").config();
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

export default (req, res) => {

  const { name, email, text } = req.body;

  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
      user: process.env.EMAIL,
      pass: process.env.PASSWORD,
    },
  });

  const mailOption = {
    from: `${email}`,
    to: `${process.env.EMAIL}`,
    subject: `New mail from ${email}`,
    text: `
    ${name} wrote:
    ${text}
    `,
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOption, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("mail send");
    }
  });

  console.log(name, email, text);
  res.send("success");
};
```

Please help

Comment: did you find the solution?? i am experiencing the same issue, its frustrating when every thing works fine in development but creates problem in production

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since your code runs fine in local and not in the deployment environment I have two suggestions.

First, make sure you have all the environment variables set.

Secondly, the way you have written your code it will always return success because `transporter.sendMail` is asynchronous and `res.send` is outside of it.

Change like,

```
transporter.sendMail(mailOption, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.send("error" + JSON.stringify(err));
    } else {
      console.log("mail send");
      res.send("success");
    }
});
```

Comment: Happy to help.. :)

Comment: Thank you. I just had the same problem and this pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you, so much!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Same problem

Comment: Thanks, bro!! you deserved much more than just a single upvote!!!